# Cancelling pthreads in a loop

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have an array of around 6 thread ids that I want to cancel in one loop. This is because I was facing certain seg faults because of these threads trying to access some invalid memory after its cleanup.  When I change the cancel type to `asynchronous`, even after the thread cancellation I keep getting segmentation faults. If I change the cancel type to `deferred` and keep the cancellation point as `pthread_join`, after 2 thread cancellations, my code gets blocked by join and it doesn't exit.

Could you suggest what can the problem be?

```
/* The cancel type is deferred and cancellation point is pthread_join. After 2    
iterations, it is unable to come out of join and gets blocked.   Here is the code:*/ 

for (int i=0;i<N_BATCH_THREADS;i++)
{
    rc = pthread_cancel(g_batch_th[i]);
    if(rc!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in pthread cancel\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Thread cancelled successfully %d\n",g_batch_th[i]);
    }
    rc = pthread_join(g_batch_th[i],&status);
    if(rc!=0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in pthread join\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Return from pthread join successful %d\n",g_batch_th[i]);
    }
    if( status != PTHREAD_CANCELED) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unexpected thread status \n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the corresponding code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand deferred cancellation. In your code example, it is the thread that is doing the cancellation of other threads that calls `pthread_join`, which does not "invoke" cancellation of the other threads. Rather, it is when the cancelled thread calls a cancellation point, that it actually terminates.

When you use asynchronous cancellation, on the other hand, the thread termination does occur more-or-less immediately, but, indeed, only more or less. Thread termination is not guaranteed to occur before `pthread_cancel` returns, so the cancelled threads may well continue running for some very small amount of time and have time to segfault before they are properly terminated. It might also be that they have registered thread cancellation callbacks, which might perhaps also segfault. I cannot speak of the specifics without knowing the details, of course.

Comment: Yea, but my problem is solved. The issue was that the threads were waiting on a cond variable. The pthread_cond_wait is also a cancellation point and it thus signals the thread and then cancels it after receiving a request. The thread thus dies holding the mutex lock. When the request for other thread's cancellation goes to pthread_cond_wait, that thread waits on the mutex to get unlocked (which is held by the dead process) and hence blocks itself forever. As a solution to this, I have implemented a cleanup process of my own instead of using cancel and join.